# How many ways can four packs of mango juice and two packs of orange juice be selected from $30$ packs of mango juice and $10$ packs of orange juice?

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:** In a box containing 30 packs of mango juice and 10 packs of orange juice, how many selections of 6 packs of juice that are composed of 4 mangoes and 2 oranges are possible?

**Choices:**
**A** 1,233,245
**B** 1,233,565
**C** 2,233,235
**D** 1,233,225

**What I did:**
I don't really know what to do  so I tried getting the number of combinations in selecting of having 4 mangoes and 2 oranges but my answer is way off.
$$\binom{30}4+\binom{10}2=27450$$
Also tried this one multiplying these numbers still I don't really know what to do, thank you for any help 
$$30*29*28*27*10*9=59194800$$

Comment: Multiplying is correct.  $\binom {30}4\times \binom {10}2=1233225$.

Comment: Note that $\binom {10}2=\frac {10\times 9}2$, for example.  You left off the denominators.

Comment: @lulu ohhh that's why, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binomial coefficients multiply, not add.
$$\binom{30}4\binom{10}2=1233225$$
and the answer is D.

Comment: Ohhh ok ok thank you so much!

Comment: @Ralph Right, please accept my answer.

Comment: Oh yea sorry wasn't able to accept it earlier since it was too early lol thanks again